# cordova avoid reloading page on in-browser back

Tags: android, cordova

I'm using Cordova 5.0.0 to load an external website by specifying this in config.xml:

```
<content src="http://www.example.com" />
```

on the website, I have links to more pages. When I tap on links it goes to the new page but when I hit back button (on Android for example) it reloads the last page (i.e. it does a full reload from server) instead of just continuing from the last spot I was in, without a refresh.
Is there a solution for that?

Comment: May be you can have some global variable flag in session storage which you can set it to true on click of back button and prevent firing complete page reload if the flag is set to true which can be cleared after page load But precise solution can be given only if you share more info and the working code.

Comment: All I want is the same behavior as in the native browsers where going back just shows me the last state that I linked from and not refreshing the previous URL.

Comment: This link should help you to do the trick in Android - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22352041/android-webview-prevent-page-reload

Comment: Unfortunately it did not help, tried playing with all options there. What I currently noticed is that it does not do a server call when hitting back, but it still shows the page as if it is reloaded with local assets. i.e. it does not return to previous state just like in native browser on same phone.

Comment: what states you gotta retain. Plz brief more.

Comment: Could you please brief on those states?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
function onBackButtonTapped() {
    history.go(-1); // Back
    //document.location.reload(true); // Reload (if needed)
}
function onDeviceReady() {
    document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackButtonTapped, false);
}
// Handle BackButton
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
```