# How do i stop a webview from refreshing in android?

Tags: android

I have a website inside a webview and i don't want users to refresh my website inside the webview in android.

I have searched whole stackoverflow but there is not a single option to stop/disable refreshing in webview for android.

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22352041/android-webview-prevent-page-reload

Comment: i have tried, it's not working